# Flow Decision Logic & IF-Else Logic

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I am just trying to develop a simple logic with Flow. And while I am using the Flow Decision logic its not working. I just need some expert advise on this.

I am calling the same flow logic from Process Builder in below 2 cases

1. On Account Object - While Creating a New Account - Called Flow to create a Case and attach
2. On Case Object - While Closing the Case - Called Flow to close the case that is attached to the Account.

In the Flow I was trying to distinguish to the above to Process Builder calls to Flow using the Flow Decision Logic in a IF ELSE logic and my doubt is that Am I using it wrong?. Because the logic works correct in separate without Decision Logic.

**Process Builder**
[image: Process Builder]

**Flow Decision Logic**
[image: Flow Decision Logic]

**Flow**
[image: Flow]

Basically my problem is that my "Default Outcome Or ELSE logic for Case in Flow Decisions" not getting called from Process Builder when I close a Case, but Account getting called from Process Builder when I Create an Account.

Can someone help me to understand whether I can use Flow Decision Logic like If-Else to identify its getting called from Process Builder (If - from Account Creation & Else - from Case Closure)? And am I using it in wrong way?

Comment: Did you type in Null?  You can scroll down on the options for your decisions and can find global and other options like empty string that can be selected.  Also, it may be worth trying to create a formula in your flow that is a boolean, based on the same if logic, and then use the result of the formula in your decision, as some times this works where other things do not.

Comment: @Logan, thanks for your reply. I have created a Boolean formula variable in Flow and while calling from Process Builder I passed True for Account & False for Case. This is checked in my Flow Decision Logic and it worked

Comment: So, it was the answer to your problem? Should I add it as an answer for you to accept?

Comment: Yes.. It solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you type in Null? You can scroll down on the options for your decisions and can find global and other options like empty string that can be selected. Also, it may be worth trying to create a formula in your flow that is a boolean, based on the same if logic, and then use the result of the formula in your decision, as some times this works where other things do not.